# conditional expectation and independence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2,Y_1, Y_2$ be random variables and $F$ be subsigma field. 
Suppose that $X_i$ is measurable on $F$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent given $F$. Then is this ture? $E(f(X_1,Y_1)g(X_2,Y_2)|F)=E(f(X_1,Y_1)|F)E(g(X_2,Y_2)|F)$

Answer (score -1):

This is false even in the simplest set up when $\mathcal{F}$ is the <del>entire</del> trivial $\sigma$-algebra of the probability space. In this case, conditional expectation is just normal expectation. Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be two independent coin flip ($\pm 1$ with probability $1/2$) and set $X_1 = Y_2$, $X_2 = Y_1$, $f(x,y) = g(x,y) = x+y$. Then LHS $= 2$ but RHS $= 0$.

Comment: conditional expectation is a random variable. If we take F which is the entire sigma algebra then LHS=f(X1,Y1)g(X2,Y2) since they are F measurable, not LHS=2.

Comment: Aha! You are right. I should have taken F to be the trivial sigma algebra.

Comment: And That is true. I knew it.

Comment: When F is the trivial sigma-algebra the result holds trivially.

Comment: @Did, could you please explain why the result holds for trivial $F$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply recall what F-measurability and independence conditionally on F mean when F is the trivial sigma-algebra.